# In case a file of X MB is loaded into SQL Server table, need to find out how much space it occupies in SQL Server – is it < X or X or > X

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

```
    In case a file of X MB is loaded into SQL Server table, 
need to find out how much space it occupies in SQL Server – is it < X or X or > X.
```

my sample `test csv file(36 bytes)`[image]

i tried testing to load a csv file into sql server file size was 36 bytes on my computer
when loaded into sql server i executed

`sp_spaceused '[dbo].[assign-test]'`

which output like this

[image]

could somebody tell me hw to decide whether file size exceeded 36 bytes or is it same

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if the file exceeds 36 *bytes* or 36 *megabytes*?

Comment: i tested on file with size 36 bytes

Comment: Do you mean loading rows from a CSV file into rows in a table, or storing the entire file as a blob of data (binary, varchar etc) in one cell in a table?

Comment: just load into sql server!!

Comment: As you can clearly see from your screen shots, SQL Server allocates data in blocks of 8k. There's no way you're going to see an increase of 36 bytes in the file.

Comment: @Gabe you mean if i `just` upload a file of say 100 MB into sql server the size will remain same

Comment: It will always be > X (unless you compress the data in some way on the way into sql) depending on how you store the data and how your table is configured.  The only reliable way to predict - is to experiment.  Simple example - ASCII text from file stored in NVARCHAR column...  doubles in size...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There will be an increase in size ,example  when a excel size of 20 KB is loaded  into SQL server the file size is checked , there's an increase (file size + index size) so there always an increase when raw file is loaded (I tested it )
```

Comment: +1 thank u for testing,but this might not be case when raw file is not used :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server writes the data into physical files on the disk in blocks called pages. The page size is 8kB and this is what you see in your result.

Depending on how exactly you store your file, it will take some of the space of this page to store it.